# json product data store creating

Tags: json

I wanna ask you a question about JSON.

I want to differentiate product by categories. How can I write that in JSON?

```
{"products":
 {"category" : "computer"[
   {"brand" : "sony"
   "price" : "$1000"},
   {"brand" : "acer"
     "price" : "$400"},]}
,

  {"category" : "cell phone"[
       {"brand" : "iphone"
        "price" : "$800"},
       {"brand" : "htc"
        "price" : "$500"},]}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need something like this:

```
{"products": 
  {"computer": 
    [
      {"brand" : "sony",
       "price" : "$1000"},
      {"brand" : "acer",
       "price" : "$400"}
    ],
   "cell phone":
    [
      {"brand" : "iphone",
        "price" : "$800"},
      {"brand" : "htc",
       "price" : "$500"}
    ] 
  }
}
```

By using the category as the key in the JSON object you can easily access all products in that category, for example:

```
>>> data['products']['computer']
[{'brand': 'sony', 'price': '$1000'}, {'brand': 'acer', 'price': '$400'}]
```

If necessary, you can also add a list of categories to top level JSON object so that you know what categories are available:

```
{"products": {...},
 "categories": ["computer", "cell phone"]
}
```