# how to access model from view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using codeIgniter 3
i have two tables one for categories has cat_id,cat_name
and another table for products has p_id,p_name,p_price,p_img,cat_id
how i can list first cat_name as title in view and list all products in divs then again second cat_name as title and list all products in dvis ....etc

I am thinking about to get cat_id,cat_name by calling  a function of model inside a controller then pass result to view 
then use

> foreach

in view 
and inside

> foreach

i send cat_id to another function to get products and make nested

> foreach

is this logic correct or not?
if yes how i can access model functions from views ??
if not what is the best practice for this issue ??

Comment: No it isn't. It's much better to make a query to fetch the data you're really after to begin with. As you describe it you will get n+1 queries (one extra query for every category). You will also violate most common "mvc" patterns by accessing the model from the view

Comment: can you give me a simple example how i can do that @JimL

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: you can construct json array as main categories and  products in side that like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002020/json-product-data-store-creating

Comment: join the 2 tables, send the data to the view, do 1 foreach loop, print category whenever cat_id has changed from previous one and print products always

Answer (score 0):

You access model function in the view. Although you can make a controller like this:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class your_controller_name extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() 
 {
        parent::__construct();
        //load model like this
        $this->load->model('your_model_name');

 }
 //your actual function start here
public function function_name($parameters)
{
  //Call model function like this
  $data['post'] = $this->Model_name->Function_name_in_model($parameters)
//pass to view like this. Then apply foreach in the view. post is the variable on which you apply foreach

     $this->load->view('path-to-the-view-in-view-folder', $data);

}
}
```

Comment: You missed the extends CI_Controller Also the first letter of class and filename should be only upper case.

Comment: thanks for correcting my mistake. I forget to add that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use this code

```
$data['post'] = $this->Model_name->Function_name_in_model($parameters)
```